# How to count number of records on the same time interval in past?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

We have two inputs `DATE_FROM` and `DATE_TO` in the format of `'YYYY-mm-dd'`, the question is to count the number of records in the period `[DATE_FROM, DATE_TO)` and `[DATE_FROM -INTERVAL(DATE_TO,DATE_FROM), DATE_FROM)`.

To count the number of records in the first interval we perform the following query

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as num_records
FROM mytable
WHERE 
    mytable.date_doc >= 'DATE_FROM 00:00:00'
AND mytable.date_doc <= 'DATE_TO 23:59:59'
```

here the date is appended by the midnight hour:minute:second to heap all records of the days on the boundary.

How to construct the query that perform the same count on the second inteval of time?

Is it possible to do it in one query to database or propose any optimal way to do it?

**EDIT**

Interval 1 (10 days): DATE_FROM = '2012-11-03 00:00:00', DATE_TO = '2012-11-12 23:59:59'

Interval 2 (10 days): DATE_FROM = '2012-10-24 00:00:00', DATE_TO = '2012-11-02 23:59:59'

```
SELECT 
   SUM(IF(DATE(mytable.date_doc) BETWEEN '2012-11-03 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-12 23:59:59', 1, 0)) AS count_interval1,
   SUM(IF(DATE(mytable.date_doc) BETWEEN '2012-10-24 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-03 00:00:00', 1, 0)) AS count_interval2
FROM mytable
```

Thank you for your expertise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(IF(DATE(mytable.date_doc) BETWEEN '2012-11-03' AND '2012-11-12', 1, 0)) AS count_interval1,
   SUM(IF(DATE(mytable.date_doc) BETWEEN SUBDATE('2012-11-03', DATEDIFF('2012-11-12', '2012-11-03') + 1) AND SUBDATE('2012-11-03', 1), 1, 0)) AS count_interval2
FROM mytable
```

No need to specify the time.

Comment: your snippet contains syntax an error, some bracket, can't get it work

Comment: i've added the snippet, don't know how to produce the valid date:'DATE_FROM-DATE_TO'

Comment: What is DATE_FROM-DATE_TO explain with example. Take any two dates as an example and explain me which data you want to extract.

Comment: yes, sorry for this unclear notation the DATE_FROM-DATE_TO should be the date minus the interval between dates

Comment: thanks, works fine. after adding where filter `WHERE mytable.date_doc >= SUBDATE('2012-11-03', DATEDIFF('2012-11-12', '2012-11-03') + 1) AND mytable.date_doc <= '2012-11-12'` even fast!